# Short story about a traveling vampire cage fighter

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I remember reading an intriguing story about a vampire fighting in cages across the country, sort of a supernatural MMA. It appeared (I think) online in the magazine Dark Recesses Press in 2008. I've been unable to locate since, would love to know author and title.